# How to stop the home button from minimizing the app?

Tags: android, android-homebutton

I know it is possible. But ho do I do so?

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
}
```

doing this does not work. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as "minimized" in Android.  An app is in the foreground or the background.  If you mean how to stop an app going to the background, then you should download the Android AOSP source code and build your own version of Android to change this behaviour.  Then replace the ROM on your device, since there is no way to override the home button behaviour for very good reasons.

Comment: Since there are many ways for your app to move to the background (user takes a phone call, user responds to a `Notification`, user moves to another app via the recent-tasks list, etc.), the HOME button is not magical.

Comment: Download the app Holo Locker... they do it